# Why does the enter name loop stay infinite & not let the rest of the code run?

Tags: python

So here is my code to calculate a student's gpa, for some reason when you input the students ID it goes right back to asking for the name.

```
gradeA = 4

gradeB = 3

gradeC = 2

gradeD = 1

gradeF = 0

#loop to keep asking for the right input
rerun = "Yes"
while rerun == "Yes":
    option = input ("Are you a student?: ")
    while option != "No" and option != "Yes":
        option = input ("Are you a student? Yes or No?: ")

    name = input ("Enter name: ")
    iD = int ( input ("Enter ID: "))

while iD < 1 or iD > 9999:
    iD = int ( input ("Enter valid ID: "))

#loop to ask for right input for credits

credit = int ( input ("\nNumber of credits for class: "))
while credit < 1 or credit > 7:
    credit = int ( input ("Enter vaid number of credits: "))

#input course name
course = input("\nName of course: ")

grade = input("\nEnter grade for course: ")
```

I think around here is when the code messes up, I could be wrong but can anyone help me figure out why the loop for the input of the name and ID is infinite.

```
#loop to ask for right grade entry
while grade != "A" and grade != "B" and grade != "C" and grade != "D" and 
grade != "F":
    grade = input("Enter valid grade: ")
```

The rest of the code won't run due to this.

```
if grade == "A":
    message = "Congragulations, keep it up!"
    gpa = float(gradeA)
elif grade == "B":
    message = "You passsed!"
    gpa = float(gradeB)
elif grade == "C":
    message = "You made it but do better!"
    gpa = float(gradeC)
elif grade == "D":
    message = "Near FAILING!"
    gpa = float(gradeD)
else:
    message = "You failed."
    gpa = float(gradeF)

print(" ")
print("="*60)
print("Name: ", format(name, ">45s"))
print("\nID: ", format(iD, "46d"))
print("="*60)
print("\nCourse: ", format(course, ">44s"))
print("\nCredit: ", format(credit, "39d"))
print("Final grade: ", format(grade, ">34s"))
print("GPA: ", format(gpa, "44.1f"))
print(" ")
print(message)

#loop to ask if another student will use the program
rerun = input ("Will you perform another student lookup? Yes or No? ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the value of option is Yes so it will continue in the loop till the condition becomes false.

```
while option == "Yes":
    name = input ("Enter name: ")
    iD = int ( input ("Enter ID: "))
```

Instead of while loop, use if condition to enter only once.

```
gradeA = 4

gradeB = 3

gradeC = 2

gradeD = 1

gradeF = 0

#loop to keep asking for the right input
rerun = "Yes"
while rerun == "Yes":
    option = input ("Are you a student?: ")
    while option != "No" and option != "Yes":
        option = input ("Are you a student? Yes or No?: ")


    #Insert whole code before this, have trimmed the code
    rerun= input("Will you perform another student?Yes or No?: ")
```

Comment: I am getting a invalid syntax error on the equal sign on this line                                                                 
                                                                                                                            
While rerun = "Yes"

Comment: Typo. It should be while rerun == "Yes"

Comment: I added the extra = but this is what happens after running it                            
    Are you a student?: Yes
    Are you a student?: Yes
    Are you a student?: Yes
    Are you a student?: Yes
    Are you a student?: Yes
    Are you a student?: No
    Are you a student?: Yes
    Are you a student?: NO
    Are you a student? Yes or No?: YEs
    Are you a student? Yes or No?: Yes
    Are you a student?: Yes
    Are you a student?:

Comment: is have edited my code, it has no relation with the while loop of "Are you a student". Looks like some typo in your inner while loop.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why "Are you a student" keeps repeating, I'm going to update my code and hopefully someone can help.

Comment: its creating bit confusion, you cna create a spearate question. There is issue of indentation. So put all your code at same time.all other while loop should come inside rerun while loop.

Comment: I made everything inside the rerun loop and everything seems to work perfectly now. Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while option == "Yes":
    name = input ("Enter name: ")
    iD = int ( input ("Enter ID: "))
```

You never give your code the option to break out of the `while` loop. I'm confused as to why you need a `while` loop, just use an `if` statement:

```
if option == "Yes":
    name = input ("Enter name: ")
    iD = int ( input ("Enter ID: "))
```

Comment: As soon as I posted this question I figured it out, I don't know why I even added that part in. Thanks for your feed back though but can I ask one question. How can I make the whole program loop so if someone enters yes to the last question in the code it starts again?

Comment: Suppose you define a variable Rerun = "Yes". Now put all your code inside a while loop. at the end of loop if other student is not there change the value of Rerun to No and it will come out of loop otherwise it will start all over again.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but can you show me an example?

Comment: have included above logic in my answer for better visibility as code